# setting OnClickListener generic method

Tags: java, android, generics, onclicklistener

I have an activity, that have different TextView's. Now, by clicking on each TextView it should open another activity. I implemented a generic way, because I wanted to remove redundant code.
So I just wanted to ask about your opinion if I am using the generic-concept in java in a correct way and if you would use a similar approach to set Listeners to multiple Views in Android?

(I used generic names for demonstration purposes and I didnt want to use the onClick declaration on the xml-Layout):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView activity1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity1);
    TextView activity2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity2);
    TextView activity3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity3);
    TextView activity4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity4);

    setOnClickListener(activity1, Activity1.class);
    setOnClickListener(activity2,  Activity2.class);
    setOnClickListener(activity3,  Activity3.class);
    setOnClickListener(activity4, Activity4.class);
}


private void setOnClickListener (TextView textView, final Class<? extends AppCompatActivity> activityClass){

    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent activityIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, activityClass);
            startActivity(activityIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Ask our opinion about what? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @GlenPierce sry, I just updated my question

Comment: I would go implementing OnClickListener on the activity, switching the view that has been clicked inside the implementation of the onClick method and then perform what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend overriding View.OnClickListener.  Decoupling the code from the Activity has the added benefit of decoupling your logic from the Activity itself, so you could use the GenericClickListener in different contexts. 
 Something like this:

```
public class GenericClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    public GenericClickListener(Activity activity, Class<? extends AppCompatActivity> activityClass) {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent activityIntent = new Intent(activity, activityClass);
            startActivity(activityIntent);
        }
    } 
}
```

And then in your onCreate() method:

```
TextView activity1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity1);
TextView activity2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity2);
TextView activity3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity3);
TextView activity4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity4);

activity1.setOnClickListener(new GenericClickListener(thia, Activity1.class));
activity2.setOnClickListener(new GenericClickListener(this, Activity2.class));
activity3.setOnClickListener(new GenericClickListener(this, Activity3.class));
activity4.setOnClickListener(new GenericClickListener(this, Activity4.class));
```

Apart from that, your implementation seems like a reasonable approach.

Comment: @RaceYourTime It should be "implements" instead of "extends" right?

Comment: @NoName123 you're right, I didn't test the code so sorry for any small errors like that. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

if this code work, it's a pretty good concept.
I would do like this

Answer (score 0):

I was making my own solution for that, and I found this thread while checking for existing elements. The following piece of code works (@RaceYouAnytime answer has few mistakes), and allows you to use `Activity` OR `Fragment` to instanciate your `StartActivity`OnClickListener`

```
public class StartActivityOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private Activity sourceActivity;
    private Class<?> destinationActivityClass;

    /**
     * Constructor to use in Activities
     * */
    public StartActivityOnClickListener(Activity srcActivity, Class<? extends AppCompatActivity> dstActivityClass)
    {
        this.sourceActivity = srcActivity;
        this.destinationActivityClass = dstActivityClass;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor to use in Fragments
     * */
    public StartActivityOnClickListener(Fragment srcFragment, Class<? extends AppCompatActivity> dstActivityClass)
    {
        this.sourceActivity = srcFragment.getActivity();
        this.destinationActivityClass = dstActivityClass;
    }

    /**
     * Overridden onClick() method building the Intent and calling startActivity() with it
     */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        sourceActivity.startActivity(new Intent(sourceActivity, destinationActivityClass));
    }
}
```

The usage stays the same, as follows

```
yourObject.setOnClickListener(new StartActivityOnClickListener(this, YourActivity.class));
```